# Python: More efficient way to get random slices from several lists

Tags: python, list, random

Here's a piece of python code I wrote to get random characters from 4 lists and append them to a separate list:

```
key.append(chr(upper[randint(0,len(upper)-1)]))
key.append(chr(lower[randint(0,len(lower)-1)]))
key.append(chr(nums[randint(0,len(nums)-1)]))
key.append(chr(symbols[randint(0,len(symbols)-1)]))
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do they all have the same length?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not necessarily. Upper is uppercase unicodes, lower - lowercase unicodes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `random.choice` + `list.extend`:

```
lsts = [upper, lower, nums, symbols]    
key.extend(chr(random.choice(x)) for x in lsts)
```

Comment: You can drop the `[...]` in this case for some added memory efficiency.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I didn't know extend worked well with generators.

Comment: It takes any iterable. Most things that accept a list and tuple take a generator too. The only exception is `str.join()` where using a list comprehension is just more efficient, see [List comprehension without \[ \] in Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/9061024)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks again. I knew about the case of `join` but didn't know that was an exception to a rule. Cool stuff.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Cool! This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Didn't quite get the part about generators, but will certainly look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sndn: I was showing cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that instead of a list comprehension, a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) would do too, which avoids creating an intermediary list object.

Answer (score 0):

> #### `random.choice(`*seq*`)`
>
> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence *seq*. If *seq* is empty, raises `IndexError`.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
key.append(chr(random.choice(upper)))
```